# Type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am writing a react application in typescript where I am trying to handle both right click and left click.

This is my interface

```
interface ButtonProps {
    value: CellValue;
    state: CellState;
    row: number;
    col: number;
    onClick(rowParam: number, colParam: number) : (e: React.MouseEvent) => void;
    onContext(rowParam: number, colParam: number) : (e: React.MouseEvent) => void;
}
```

Now I have declared the callback function like

```
const handleContextMenu = (rowParam: number, cellParam: number) => (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) : void => {
      e.preventDefault();
}
```

and finally declared my component like

```
<Button 
  key={`${rowIndex}*${cellIndex}`} 
  value={cell.value} 
  state={cell.state} 
  onClick={handleCellClick}
  onContext={handleContextMenu}
  row={rowIndex} 
  col={cellIndex} 
/>
```

But I get an error

```
Type '(rowParam: number, cellParam: number) => (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void' is not assignable to type '(rowParam: number, colParam: number) => (e: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) => void'.
  Type '(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void' is not assignable to type '(e: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'e' and 'e' are incompatible.
      Type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>'.
        Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLDivElement': align, accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, and 111 more.  TS2322

    53 |                 state={cell.state} 
    54 |                 onClick={handleCellClick}
  > 55 |                 onContext={handleContextMenu}
       |                 ^
    56 |                 row={rowIndex} 
    57 |                 col={cellIndex} 
    58 |             />
```

I don't know much about typescript but according to me HTMLDivElement should be of type HTMLElement right?

Comment: I don't know much about typescript either, but it seems to me that the parameter on both onclick and onContext should be the event object. You have some (rowParam: number, colParam: number)  params

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Solution

Change from **HTMLDivElement** to **Element** solve your problem.

```
// Before
const handleContextMenu = (...) => (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) : void => {
  ...
}
// After
const handleContextMenu = (...) => (e: React.MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) : void => {
  ...
}
```

#### Explanation

The hierarchy relationship is as below:

⌞Element
  ⌞HTMLElement
    ⌞HTMLDivElement

- ref: [Interface HTMLDivElement](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.htmldivelement.html)

The error message is showing something like:

> Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLDivElement': align, accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, and 111 more.  TS2322

This is telling that there are some props that belong to `Element` could not be found in `HTMLDivElement`.

Comment: It happened to me that I did not use `React.MouseEvent`, nor did I import `MouseEvent` explicitly from 'react'. Then TS screams that `MouseEvent` is not generic (some other interface).

Answer (score 8):

So, for those people who are getting

`Type 'MouseEvent' is not generic.`

Make sure you are importing from `React`

`import { MouseEvent } from 'react';`

or

`React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>`